# Unable to set proxy in mechanize.browser successfully

Tags: python, browser, proxy, mechanize, mechanize-python

I am writing an application where it retrieves data from a film database. To achieve the same, I am using BeautifulSoup and Mechanize for the same.

Thus, while setting the proxy as with in the below ways:

---

**choice 1:**

```
br.set_proxies({"http": "tim:abc1234@localhost:3128"})
```

**O/P**:

```
URLError: urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

---

**choice 2:**

```
br.set_proxies({'http':'localhost',
                    'https':'localhost'})
```

**O/P**:

```
httperror_seek_wrapper: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

---

**choice 3:**

```
br.set_proxies(
     {"http": "tim:password@myproxy.example.com:3128",
      "ftp": "proxy.example.com"})
```

**O/P**:

```
URLError: urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

---

Reference Docs:

[Mechanize official docs](https://mechanize.readthedocs.io/en/latest/browser_api.html)

[Mechanize docs - pdf](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/mechanize/latest/mechanize.pdf)

Despite following the above reference links I am still unable to set the proxy properly. 
Any leads would be highly appreciated.

Comment: first you need working proxy server or address to working proxy server. It seems you use addresses for not working proxies or not existing proxy servers.

Comment: @furas, ohh...I thought it could be done without it too, by some kind of virtual proxy. However, can you please help with a working proxy? How can it be done?

Comment: there are pages with lists of free proxy servers like https://www.sslproxies.org/ but often they doesn't works and you have test many url. For testing requests (to see what is in headers, cookies, etc, I use local proxy server [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com/) or [mitmproxy](https://mitmproxy.org/)